# Dequeuing Duplicates

Tags: c, duplicates, queue

I am having a problem. I understand how to dequeue duplicates if they are first using head and tail, but I dont understand how achieve the same effect with the default interface function of the queue: `initializeQueue(), enqueue(), dequeue(), front() and queueEmpty()`

`q1 = 1,1,1,4,5` to `q1 = 4,5` it is assumed that the duplicates are always first in the list

```
int dequeueEquivalent(Queue* queue)
{
    int dequeue= 0;
    for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
       //if statment maybe?
        dequeue(queue);
        dequeue++;
    }
    return dequeue;

}
```

One of the ideas is to dequeue everything and then enqueue everything that is not equal to `front()` value. I dont know if that the correct way to do it. The function above servers as a starting point for me, feel free to change everything if needed. The idea might be wrong so I am open to any suggestions

Comment: "Everything not equal to `front()` value" is probably not correct — if the input queue is `q1 = { 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6 }`, then the front value should be preserved. Maybe you need to create a new, empty queue and copy values from the old to the new. You also need to be able to check whether a value already occurs in the output queue, and remove both the potential new and the old entry if it does.  That's trickier — you need access to the elements of the queue by location without removing them.  You also need to worry about sequencing — you may need a double-ended queue (deque).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler added clarification sry for the misinformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the duplicates like stated is first in the list you can do this

```
int dequeueEquivalent(Queue* queue)
{
    int dequeue= 0;
    int head = front(*queue);
    for(int i =0; i<5; i++){
     if(front(*queue) == head )
        {
            dequeue(*queue);
            dequeue++;
        }
    }
    return dequeue;

}
```